# User-defined overloaded operator * with std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, templates, stl, operator-overloading, duration

I've created a Frequency class template intended to work in conjunction with [std::chrono::duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). A Frequency object stores a number of cycles per unit duration (both using template parameters for their types). The idea is that multiplying a Frequency by a duration produces an object of type Rep. Here's the class definition. I've omitted all but the relevant members.

```
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

template <typename Rep, typename Period = std::ratio<1>>
class Frequency
{
public:
    explicit Frequency(Rep cycles) : _cycles{cycles} { }

    friend Rep operator *(const Frequency<Rep, Period>& f, const duration<Rep, Period> d)
    {
        return f._cycles * d.count();
    }
    friend Rep operator *(const duration<Rep, Period> d, const Frequency<Rep, Period>& f)
    {
        return f._cycles * d.count();
    }
private:
    Rep _cycles; ///> The number of cycles per period.
};
```

The problem (I think) is that std::chrono::duration also overloads the * operator, as follows:

```
template< class Rep1, class Period, class Rep2 >
duration<typename std::common_type<Rep1,Rep2>::type, Period>
    constexpr operator*( const duration<Rep1,Period>& d,
                         const Rep2& s );

template< class Rep1, class Rep2, class Period >
duration<typename std::common_type<Rep1,Rep2>::type, Period>
    constexpr operator*( const Rep1& s,
                         const duration<Rep2,Period>& d );
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), each of these methods

> Converts the duration d to one whose rep is the common type between Rep1 and Rep2, and multiplies the number of ticks after conversion by s.

I believe that the compiler is trying to use these overloaded operator templates instead of my overloads. When I write the following code:

```
Frequency<double> f{60.0};
duration<double> d{1.0};
double foo = f * d;
```

I get something like the following error in VS2013:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\type_traits(1446) : error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'double' to 'Frequency<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>'
        Constructor for class 'Frequency<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>' is declared 'explicit'
        source_file.cpp(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::common_type<Frequency<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>,Rep>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Rep=double
        ]
```

And line 1446 is the VS implementation of `std::common_type`.

So, is there a way to ensure that my overloads get called instead of those in std::chrono::duration? I know that I could solve the problem by not using operator overloading and writing a differently named method instead, but I'd like to get a better understanding of what's going on here if possible. (Plus the overloads are more convenient.)

Also, I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but I was unable to find anything similar after searching.

Comment: Works under [clang and gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5449cf8b49c47faf) for me. Care to show a compilable example that reproduces your error?

Comment: @jrok: Your code is a compilable example that reproduces the error, you just tested the wrong compilers: http://rextester.com/GZDPQ2819

Comment: @jrok: I'm still trying to figure out why it's trying to instantiate `std::common_type<Frequency<double>,Rep>`, much less why it's failing... oh....

Comment: @MooingDuck I suspect there's a bug in their `common_type` implementation, then?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp: It isn't.  I'll post an answer

Comment: oh, so the error is triggered during *overload resolution*? thank god I'm not working with *msvc*.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp It looks like it. And I share your sentiment :)

Comment: If you remove the  explicit keyword in the constructor, it can be compiled with Visual studio 2013 express.

Comment: Actually, I think MSVC may be correct here.

Comment: Aha. The g++ implementation of `std::common_type` is not as specified in the Standard. Somebody decided to make it more "SFINAE friendly". Officially, if `(true ? declval<X>() : declval<Y>())` is ill-formed, so is `common_type<X,Y>`.  But in g++'s implementation it acts as though `common_type<X,Y>` is a struct without any `type` member.

Comment: See also proposal N3843, which would make g++ correct and the original code from this question well-formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
Frequency<double> f{60.0};
duration<double> d{1.0};
double foo = f * d;
```

The compiler says "oh, I have to find an `operator*` that takes a `Frequency<double>` and a `std::chrono::duration<double>`.  What `operator*` possibilities are there?  And it generates a list of possibilities, composed mostly of these two:

```
friend Rep operator *(const Frequency<Rep, Period>& f, const duration<Rep, Period> d)
{
    return f._cycles * d.count();
}

template< class Rep1, class Rep2, class Period >
duration<typename std::common_type<Rep1,Rep2>::type, Period>
constexpr operator*( const Rep1& s,
                     const duration<Rep2,Period>& d );
```

Then, it tries to figure out *exactly* what each of the signatures are.  The first one is:

```
Rep operator *(const Frequency<Rep, Period>& f, const duration<Rep, Period> d)
```

and trying the second one results in:

```
error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'double' to 'Frequency<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>'
        Constructor for class 'Frequency<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>' is declared 'explicit'
        source_file.cpp(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::common_type<Frequency<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>,Rep>' being compiled
```

Since it can't even figure out what the signature *is*, it can't figure out which one to select, and it gives up.  I would consider this a bug in MSVC's implementation of `operator*` in this case.

The obvious workaround is to make `common_type<Frequency<double>,Rep>` able to compile, possibly by removing the `explicit` limitation on the constructor. [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) observes it might be smarter and more useful to instead specialize `common_type`:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename Rep, typename Period>
    struct common_type<Frequency<Rep,Period>, std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>>   
    {
        typedef Rep type;
    };
    template <typename Rep, typename Period>
    struct common_type<std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>, Frequency<Rep,Period>>   
    {
        typedef Rep type;
    };
}
```

Comment: if remove the two operator* function, you still get the same error in the MS compiler.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, because Microsoft's `operator*` is the problem.  The user's `operator*` is only tangentially related.

Comment: That workaround does indeed work, thanks! Sadly, this won't work for a related type I've written (Velocity) that can't be converted to the duration's Rep type. Shame shame, MSVC...

Comment: @JonathanSharman You are allowed to specialize `std::common_type` though.  And in fact the Standard notes "Such specializations are needed when only explicit conversions are desired among the template arguments."

Comment: @aschepler Interesting. How should I go about specializing `std::common_type` for my classes? What type should `type` be?

Comment: @JonathanSharman: Effectively common type is the return type of `A+B` or in your case, `A*B`.  Your code shows you want `Rep` for that.