# operator/ of std::chrono::duration and custom type with clang

Tags: c++, clang, c++-chrono

Consider a custom type that is meant to multiply and divide a specific instantiation of a duration:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Foo {};

using Duration = std::chrono::seconds;

inline Duration operator*(Duration d, Foo) {
    std::cout << "multiplying some time with Foo\n";
    return d;
}

inline Duration operator/(Duration d, Foo) {
    std::cout << "dividing some time by Foo\n";
    return d;
}

int main() {
    Duration d;
    Foo f;
    d * f;
    d / f;
}
```

This code compiles without warnings with gcc, but fails with clang ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xtvs7ZgRVIx3PcWs))

```
In file included from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/clang-7.0.0/include/c++/v1/chrono:1259:81: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::common_type<long long, Foo>'
                          typename common_type<typename _Duration::rep, _Rep2>::type>::value>
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/opt/wandbox/clang-7.0.0/include/c++/v1/chrono:1272:7: note: in instantiation of default argument for '__duration_divide_imp<std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1> >, Foo>' required here
    : __duration_divide_imp<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/wandbox/clang-7.0.0/include/c++/v1/chrono:1279:10: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::chrono::__duration_divide_result<std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1> >, Foo, false>' requested here
typename __duration_divide_result<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2>::type
         ^
prog.cc:22:7: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator/' [with _Rep1 = long long, _Period = std::__1::ratio<1, 1>, _Rep2 = Foo]
    d / f;
```

Note that `operator*` works just fine with both compilers.

The actual code is a bit more convoluted, using a friend method defined within a class-scope type which performs overflow-safe integer operation on durations, but shows exactly the same symptoms.

The issue looks similar to: [User-defined overloaded operator * with std::chrono::duration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24022142/620382), but that's a different operator and compiler.

Comment: FWIW, you really shouldn't overload operators for types you do not know.  Free functions are a lot safer and remove a lot of the ambiguity.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on safety & ambiguity. I'm having a hard time seeing ambiguity in this case, where both operands are concrete types. I understand uniquely named free functions are easier to reason about, but they are simply not as concise. In fact in the code, which works fine with gcc, I added the specific duration factor type introducing safe integer multiplication without having to change any of the code using to polish notation. I consider that a pretty significant feature of C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver but this code **does** own `Foo`, so it's OK to define what `d / f` means. Would you say it's bad to define `operator/(const Foo&, int)`? Why is this different?

Comment: @JonathanWakely The OP does not own `std::chrono::duration`.  the `int` case is benign since operators for buiilt in types can be overloaded so nothing will break.  Nothing stops `std` from breaking the OP's code in the future.

Comment: @NathanOliver _"operators for buiilt in types can be overloaded so nothing will break."_ -- eh? Why is it any different? Alternatively, why is `operator/(const chrono::duration&, const Foo&)` bad but `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo&)` OK?

Comment: And yes, I know the OP does not own `duration`, that was implied by the emphasis on "but this code **does** own `Foo`".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a libc++ bug to me (and a bug I wrote).  Here is a very lightly tested fix:

```
--- a/include/chrono
+++ b/include/chrono
@@ -1289,7 +1289,12 @@ struct __duration_divide_result<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2, false>
 template <class _Rep1, class _Period, class _Rep2>
 inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
 _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR
-typename __duration_divide_result<duration<_Rep1, _Period>, _Rep2>::type
+typename enable_if
+<
+    !__is_duration<_Rep2>::value &&
+    is_convertible<_Rep2, typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type>::value,
+    duration<typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type, _Period>
+>::type
 operator/(const duration<_Rep1, _Period>& __d, const _Rep2& __s)
 {
     typedef typename common_type<_Rep1, _Rep2>::type _Cr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I do anything further with respect to reporting the bug?

Comment: It would be a good idea to file this: https://bugs.llvm.org/  I did a quick search and don't see one already entered.